# Android E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

When I run the app, nothing is visible. Please help me

There seems to be no problem, but I have been wondering about this for a few days.

The debugger shows this warning message:

Android E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

I don't know what the hell is wrong.

1. Here is my MainActivity code

```
private void setUrl(final String dateUrl) 
{
        myRecyclerView.setAlpha(0.5f);
        loadingPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        noteTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                url = "http://data.nba.net/10s/prod/v1/" + dateUrl + "/scoreboard.json";
                final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(NbaApp.getCurrentActivity());
                JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        jsonObject = response;
                        gameCardsCreater = new GameCardsCreater(jsonObject);
                        if (gameCardsCreater.isGameNight()) {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    gameCardsCreater.populateCards();
                                    setCardsCreater();
                                    myRecyclerView.setEnabled(true);
                                    myRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    loadingPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    myRecyclerView.setAlpha(1);
                                    runLayoutAnimation(myRecyclerView);
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            myRecyclerView.setEnabled(false);
                            myRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            noteTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            noteTextView.setText(R.string.no_games_tonight);
                            loadingPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        myRecyclerView.setEnabled(false);
                        myRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        noteTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        noteTextView.setText(R.string.error_getting_info);
                        loadingPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
                requestQueue.add(objectRequest);
            }
        }).start();

    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    public void setCardsCreater() {
        gameArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        gameArrayList = gameCardsCreater.getGameArrayList();
        GameAdapter adapter = new GameAdapter(gameArrayList, new CustomItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {
                if (isNetworkConnected()) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                    extras.putString("gameDate", gameArrayList.get(position).getGameDate());
                    extras.putString("gameId", gameArrayList.get(position).getGameId());
                    extras.putString("homeTeamWins", gameArrayList.get(position).getHomeTeamWins());
                    extras.putString("awayTeamWins", gameArrayList.get(position).getAwayTeamWins());
                    extras.putBoolean("isGameActivated", gameArrayList.get(position).isGameActive());
                    extras.putString("homeTeamName", gameArrayList.get(position).getHomeTeamName());
                    extras.putString("awayTeamName", gameArrayList.get(position).getAwayTeamName());
                    extras.putBoolean("isGameOver", gameArrayList.get(position).isGameOver());
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
                    myIntent.putExtras(extras);
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(NbaApp.getCurrentActivity(), "Check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemLongClick(View v, int position) {
            }
        });

        myRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

    }
```

2.Here is my RecyclerView adapter code, GameAdapter

```
public class GameAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GameAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private final CustomItemClickListener listener;
    private ArrayList<Game> gameList;

    public GameAdapter(ArrayList<Game> myValues, CustomItemClickListener listener) {
        this.gameList = myValues;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView homeTeamNameTextView;
        private TextView awayTeamNameTextView;
        private ImageView awayTeamLogoImageView;
        private ImageView homeTeamLogoImageView;
        private TextView awayTeamScoreTextView;
        private TextView homeTeamScoreTextView;
        private TextView awayTeamWinsTextView;
        private TextView homeTeamWinsTextView;
        private TextView nuggetTextView;
        private TextView gameTimeTextView;

        MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            awayTeamNameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.awayteamname);
            homeTeamNameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hometeamname);
            awayTeamLogoImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.awayteamlogo);
            homeTeamLogoImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hometeamlogo);
            awayTeamScoreTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.awayteamscore);
            homeTeamScoreTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hometeamscore);
            awayTeamWinsTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.awayteamwins);
            homeTeamWinsTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hometeamwins);
            nuggetTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nuggettext);
            gameTimeTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.gameTime);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View listItem = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_game, parent, false);
        final MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(listItem);
        listItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.onItemClick(v, myViewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Game game = gameList.get(position);
        holder.homeTeamNameTextView.setText(game.getHomeTeamName());
        holder.awayTeamNameTextView.setText(game.getAwayTeamName());
        Picasso.get().load(game.getAwayTeamImage()).into(holder.awayTeamLogoImageView);
        Picasso.get().load(game.getHomeTeamImage()).into(holder.homeTeamLogoImageView);
        holder.awayTeamScoreTextView.setText(game.getAwayTeamScore());
        holder.homeTeamScoreTextView.setText(game.getHomeTeamScore());
        holder.awayTeamWinsTextView.setText(game.getAwayTeamWins());
        holder.homeTeamWinsTextView.setText(game.getHomeTeamWins());
        if (game.getNugget().isEmpty())
            holder.nuggetTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        else
            holder.nuggetTextView.setText(game.getNugget());
        holder.gameTimeTextView.setText(game.getGameTime());
        if (game.isGameActive())
            holder.gameTimeTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
        else
            holder.gameTimeTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#B4B4B4"));
        if (!game.getHomeTeamScore().isEmpty() && !game.getAwayTeamScore().isEmpty()) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(game.getHomeTeamScore()) > Integer.parseInt(game.getAwayTeamScore())) {
                holder.homeTeamScoreTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                holder.awayTeamScoreTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#B4B4B4"));
            } else if (Integer.parseInt(game.getHomeTeamScore()) < Integer.parseInt(game.getAwayTeamScore())) {
                holder.homeTeamScoreTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#B4B4B4"));
                holder.awayTeamScoreTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            } else {
                holder.homeTeamScoreTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#B4B4B4"));
                holder.awayTeamScoreTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#B4B4B4"));
            }
        }

    }
    
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return gameList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it called correctly `myRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` in your source code. I saw there is many part for visible `gone` of `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Please edit your tag.